# Laravel 4 duplicate database entry

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I have two models one for user and the other for license. If the user is of usertype dentist or dental hygienist then they will need to input their license information. In my user model I have a rule that says one license belongs to one user. In my license model I have a rule that says the license belongs to the user. When I submit the license number, state, and expiration date for a user who is of the correct usertype, their information is stored in the database just fine. **The problem i am having is when that same user goes back to their profile and updates for example, their expiration date then for some reason in the database there are two entries for that user.**

**Modified Controller**

```
            if( $user->usertype == 'dental hygienist' || $user->usertype == 'dentist'  && !isset($license_num ) && !isset($license_state) && !isset($license_exp)) {

                $license = new License();
                $license->user_id = $id;
                $license->temp_id = $id;
                $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
                $license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
                $license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

                $license->save();
            }else if ($user->usertype == 'dental hygienist' || $user->usertype == 'dentist'  && isset($license_num ) && isset($license_state) && isset($license_exp)){
                $license = License::find($id);
                $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
                $license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
                $license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

                $license->save();
            }
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container profile-wrapper" style="position: relative;top:170px;">
        <div class="col-lg-8 profile-content">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">{{ucwords($user->firstname)}}, Update Your Profile Below</div>
                @if($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>
                    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error"><b>:message</b></li>')) }}
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="panel-body">

                    {{ Form::model($user, array('url' => array('user/profile/update', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'form-inline edit-form')) }}

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                                {{ Form::text('firstname', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                                {{ Form::text('lastname', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                            {{ Form::text('zipcode', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}

                        </div>


                    </fieldset>



                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Professional Information</legend>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="experience">Years Experience</label>
                            {{ Form::text('temp_experience', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="hourlyrate">Hourly Rate</label>
                            {{ Form::text('temp_hourly_rate', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')) }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group temp_travel_input">
                            <label for="zipcode">Willingness to Travel</label>
                            {{ Form::text('temp_travel', null, array('class' => 'form-control  input-sm')) }}
                        </div><!-- end .form-group -->

                        <!-- conditional statement for different temp types -->

                        <div class="form-group mtop-20">
                            <label for="temp_software_experience">Software Experience:</label><br>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox"  value="Practiceworks" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Practiceworks",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Practiceworks
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox"  value="Softdent" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Softdent",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Softdent
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox"  value="Ortho trac" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Ortho trac",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Ortho trac
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox"  value="Dentrix" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Dentrix",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Dentrix
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Easy Dental" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Easy Dental",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Easy Dental
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Eaglesoft" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Eaglesoft",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Eaglesoft
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Other" <?php $software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience); if(in_array("Other",$software)) echo "checked"; ?>> Other
                            </label>

                        </div><!-- end .form-group -->


                    </fieldset>

                    @if($user->usertype == "dental hygienist")

                    <div class="form-group mtop-20">
                        <label for="temp_software_experience">Anesthesia Certified:</label><br>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input name="answer[]" type="radio"  value="1" > Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input name="answer[]" type="radio"  value="0"> No
                        </label>

                    </div><!-- end .form-group -->

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>License Information</legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="license_number">License Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="license_number" value="@if($user->license){{$user->license->license_number}}@endif" required/>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="license_state">License State</label>
                            <select name="license_state" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <option selected value="@if($user->license){{$user->license->license_state}}@endif">@if($user->license){{$user->license->license_state}}@endif</option>
                                <option value="">-- UNITED STATES --</option>
                                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="California">California</option>
                                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                                <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                                <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                                <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                                <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                                <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                                <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                                <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                                <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                            <div class="form-group mtop-20">
                                <label for="experience">Expiration Date</label>

                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon input-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="expiration date" value="@if($user->license){{$user->license->license_expiration_date}}@endif" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    @endif


                    {{Form::hidden('uid', $user->id)}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::submit('Update', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control'))}}
                    </div>

                        {{ Form::close() }}

                    </div><!-- end .panel-body -->

                </div><!-- end .panel/default -->

            </div><!-- end .profile-content -->

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                image
            </div>
        </div><!-- end .container/profile-wrapper -->
@stop
```

**Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{

    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'zipcode' => 'required|min:5|numeric',
        'temp_experience' => 'required|min:1|max:50|numeric',
        'temp_travel' =>   'required|numeric',
        'temp_hourly_rate' => 'required|numeric|min:10'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/' . $id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        $software_checked = Input::get('software');
        if(is_array($software_checked))
        {
            $imploded_software = implode(',', $software_checked);
        }


        // store
        $user = User::find($id);

        $license_num = Input::get('license_number');
        $license_state = Input::get('license_state');
        $license_exp = Input::get('expiration_date');

        $user->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname      = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->zipcode = Input::get('zipcode');
        $user->temp_experience = Input::get('temp_experience');
        $user->temp_travel = Input::get('temp_travel');
        $user->temp_hourly_rate = Input::get('temp_hourly_rate');
        $user->temp_software_experience = $imploded_software;
        if(isset($license_num) && isset($license_state) && isset($license_exp)){
            $user->approved = 1;
        }
        else{
            $user->approved = 0;
        }
        if( $user->save() ) {
            if( $user->usertype == 'dental hygienist' || $user->usertype == 'dentist'  && !$user->license->temp_id ) {

    could this be the problem?->$license = new License();
                $license->user_id = $id;
                $license->temp_id = $id;
                $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
                $license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
                $license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

                $license->save();
            }

                // redirect
                Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!!');
                return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'');
        }
    }

}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {



    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    public static function getTemps()
    {

       // Create a array of allowed types.
        $types = array('dental hygienist', 'dentist', 'dental assistance');

        // Get what type the user selected.
        $type = Input::get('temptype');

        //Get user location
        //$location = Input::get('zipcode');


        // Make sure it is a valid type.
        if(!in_array($type, $types))
        {
            return App::abort(500, "Invaild temptype.");
        }

      $temps =  DB::table('users')
            ->join('availability', 'users.id', '=', 'availability.userid')
            ->select('users.id', 'users.firstname', 'users.lastname', 'users.zipcode', 'users.salary', 'availability.dateavailable')
            ->where('usertype', $type)
           //->where('zipcode', $location)
            ->get();

        return $temps;
    }

    public function license()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('License');
    }
```

**License Model**

```
<?php

class License extends Eloquent {


    protected  $table = 'temps_license';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }



}
```

Comment: `could this be the problem?->$license = new License();` <- You are indeed correct you are creating a new record every time.

Comment: I tried modify my controller to check if the fields are set and if they are then use $license = License::find($id); and save the data but its not working. When I echo $license its blank. I modified my controller above @FruityP

Comment: @elodev, in this case, you are loading a License with the same $id of the User...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$license = new License();
$license->user_id = $id;
$license->temp_id = $id;
$license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
$license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
$license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

$license->save();
```

With

```
$license = $user->license;
$license->temp_id = $id;
$license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
$license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
$license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

$license->save();
```

You could also modify the migration file to have the `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->unique()`, If you want to make sure that no duplicates are created